# how to get contacts from phonebook when pressing a button in android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a program. There is also a function I want to ask. I have a button and a textview. I want that when I press the button, my phonebook is opened so that I could select a contact number. After finished, the selected contact number will be displayed in the textview. Currently, I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the onClick call this..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Uri.parse("content://contacts/"));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

override the `onActivityResult` method, use `Cursor` to move to the selected contact and display it in your textview

This could look something like this...

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
{
    Uri contactData = data.getData();
     Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
     c.moveToFirst();
     String name;
     name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
    TextView tv;
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selected_contact_textview);
    tv.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Could you make the step use cursor to move selected contact clearly please?

Comment: I used your code, put I modified some of them:
 btnPhonebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent pb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pb, 1);
   }
  });
        
    }

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
   Uri contactData = data.getData();
   Cursor contactCursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
   String cellNoFromPhonebook;
   if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    cellNoFromPhonebook = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    etNumber.setText(cellNoFromPhonebook);
   }
  }
 }

Comment: However, I can just pick up the name and display it to the edittext, I do not know how to pick up the phone number from a contact. Moreover, if a contact has more than one phone number, how can I choose one of them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Following code shows an easy way to read all phone numbers and names:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null); 
while (phones.moveToNext()) 
{
 String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
 String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 
}
phones.close();
```

Comment: but how can I pick up a phone number when user clicked to a record? Moreover, if a contact have more than one phone number, how can I get it?